# How I can count duplicate with Strings?

Tags: java

I am new to programming , I am developing with strings , I am not yet with Hash Maps my only problem is the last letter. The last letter for example s  The value contains 2 instead one. How can I do that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   

    String word = "Chris", 
        curr_char,
        next_char;
    int length_string = word.length(), 
        count = 0;
    char end_letter = word.charAt(word.length()-1);
    String end =  Character.toString(end_letter);
    for(int index = 0; index < word.length(); index++)
    {
        curr_char = word.substring(index, index+1);

        for(int next_index = 0;next_index<word.length(); next_index++)
        {
            next_char  = word.substring(next_index, next_index+1);
            if (curr_char.equalsIgnoreCase(next_char))
            {
                count = 1;
            }
            if(curr_char.contains(end))
            {
                 count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(word.charAt(index) + " " + count);   
    }
}
```

Comment: _The last letter for example s The value contains 2 instead one_ I am not sure I understood that part... Please try to propose a [mcve] to give a complete explanation of the problem

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Please provide more context.

Comment: [mcve] [mcve] [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post properly formatted code, as it is really hard to read it the way it is formatted right now

Comment: What do you want you code to do? ....print how many times a char exists in a String?!

Comment: I have edited your code format, but I notice by checking the revision that I removed a `}` ... please check if this was a typo here, **or revert the edit** (my bad) It was probably the closing bracket of the class (not provided here)

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues in your algorithm logic. The algorithm will not work with strings such as "Chriss" or "Chcriss". Your output with input string "Chriss" would be

C 1
h 1
r 1
i 1
s 2
s 1

Additionally, you have 2 iterations, which makes the algorithm not so efficient. An algorithm to be efficient should take less time (high speed) & less space (less memory).

Your above problem is usually solved by having an integer array, say *charArrayCount* , of size 26, as there are 26 letters in the English alphabet. Each element of this integer array represents a character in the alphabet & is used to count how many times it appears in a string. You would iterate through each character in your string & use the formula,

```
charArrayCount[25 - ('z' - ch)] += 1;
```

where 'ch' would be a character in your string. You could then iterate through your array *'charArrayCount'* & get those values > 1. You would have to take care of upper case & lower case characters.

In this case, you have only 1 iteration through the string & no matter how long your string is, say a thousand characters, you create space for an integer array of 26 elements only.

Try this & see if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

This code runs perfect now :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

 String word = "Chris" , curr_char , next_char;
 int length_string = word.length();
 char end_letter = word.charAt(word.length()-1);
 String end =  Character.toString(end_letter);

 for(int index = 0; index <word.length(); index++)
 {
  int count = 0; //resetting the value of count every time
  curr_char = word.substring(index, index+1);


  for(int next_index = 0;next_index<word.length(); next_index++)
  {
     next_char  = word.substring(next_index, next_index+1);
     if (curr_char.equalsIgnoreCase(next_char))
     {
     count = count + 1;
     //if any character repeats it increase the value of count
     }

 }
System.out.println(word.charAt(index) + " " + count);   
}

}
```

Test this once...

Comment: What have you done, why, this should be explain at least by pointing the codes that have been changed. OP need to learn from this too. Please [edit] the answer to be more complet

Comment: test the code now and I had mentioned comments so do read them